# WCF http activation without IIS

Tags: wcf, http

Is it possible to enable HTTP components for WCF without installing IIS. When i try to enable the HTTP components on windows server 2008 it forces me to enable the web server components.
Is there a workaround by not installing webserver. 
(any solution other than self hosting or windows service)
thanks
Ben

Comment: WAS shares some components with IIS.  See the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx for why you need those certain components installed.

Answer (score 1):

WCF services can be hosted in any managed .NET application, not only IIS. You can either host it inside a windows service, or create a standard .NET executable to host the service (self-hosting). You can configure your end point to http eventhough the WCF is hosted outside IIS.

Check this article for more insight:

[Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic3)

Comment: can it be hosted just by WAS, instead of using windows service or self hosted